# How to ensure that an extending class must set property values in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, typescript

If I have a class `foo`:

```
class Foo {
  id: number
  name: string

  sayHi() {
    console.log('hi')
  }
}
```

How can I ensure that any class extending from foo must set values for `id` and `name`?

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  // must set these values
  id = 1
  name = 'bar'
}
```

Is there name for this concept or pattern? I can't have `Foo` as an interface because it has to have methods, that the inherited classes can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `Foo` a constructor which requires them as parameters:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {
    // Validate them here if desired
  }

  sayHi() {
    console.log('hi');
  }
}
```

Since a subclass must call its superclass constructor (implicitly or explicitly), an attempt to do so without passing in the necessary arguments will get flagged by the TypeScript compiler: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.` For instance, these both fail:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
}
const b = new Bar();   // Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

and

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super();           // Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
  }
}
```

---

Note the interesting TypeScript feature used there: Because we've given an access modifier on the constructor parameters, instance properties are automatically created and set to those values when the constructor is called. It's equivalent to:

```
class Foo {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    // Validate them here if desired
  }

  sayHi() {
    console.log('hi');
  }
}
```

(Since the default modifier is `public`.)